# How to show that the event is closed in this GridView when the number of bookings reaches number of seats?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am struggling with a little strange problem that I don't know how to solve it. I am developing a small web-based events management system. The events will be listed in a GridView. Now, I am looking for a way to highlight the event or put a symbol besides it saying (Closed) when the number of bookings reaches the number of seats in that event. How to do that?

I have the following database design:

```
Events Table: ID, Title, Description, Location, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, NumberOfSeats, IsActive
BookingDetails Table: BookingID, EventID, NetworkID
```

*(IsActive is a flag that shows if the event is still active or it becomes inactive)*

My ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ListOfAvailableEvents_GrivView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    DataKeyNames="ID" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333"
                    GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' OnClick="lnkTitle_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDateTime" HeaderText="Start Date & Time" SortExpression="StartDateTime" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDateTime" HeaderText="End Date & Time" SortExpression="EndDateTime" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PM_RegistrationSysDBConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT     ID, Title, Description, Location, StartDateTime, EndDateTime
                            FROM         dbo.Events
                            WHERE     (IsActive = 1)
                            ORDER BY ID DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just bind the CSS class field the IsActive property, and css styles to present the information.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkStatus" runat="server" CssClass='status<%# Eval("IsActive")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

CSS:

```
.statusTrue { background: green; }

.statusFalse { background: red; }
```

Comment: also set `IsEnabled` property of the LinkButton

Comment: Why you are using the LinkButton? Besides that, how will you know if the number of bookings reaches the number of seats?

Comment: Your comment on the *IsActive* flag made me believe that you were marking the event as inactive when it reached the number of seats. (Best place to do this would be while making the booking). Using the link button to render an `<a>` tag. You could also use a `Label` if you want a span. The main trick is adding the correct css class.